# Plugin Installation error using Plugman - Phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, plugman

I installed plugman in phonegap but later while installing plugin it show me following error:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>plugman install --platform android --project c:\testApp
--plugin org.apache.cordova.camera
Installing "org.apache.cordova.camera" for android
Failed to install 'org.apache.cordova.camera':TypeError: Cannot read property 't
rim' of null
    at new SemVer (C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\node_
modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\semver\semver.js:253:18)
    at compare (C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\node_mod
ules\cordova-lib\node_modules\semver\semver.js:409:10)
    at Function.gte (C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\nod
e_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\semver\semver.js:458:10)
    at C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\cord
ova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:590:45
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\node_
modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\plugman\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\plugman\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
    at C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\q\q.
js:509:49
    at flush (C:\Users\INTEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\node_modul
es\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
Cannot read property 'trim' of null

C:\Program Files\nodejs>
```

Cannot read property 'trim' of NULL. Now what does this mean?

Comment: I don't know what was the exact problem with Plugman. But later I switched to cordova CLI and installed it as accordingly. Use following Guide http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue using the cordova cli.

what i found was that the android platform had a different set of plugins then cordova plugin list showed.  to fixed this i just removed the android platform and then added it back.  After that everything was fixed.

I hope this helps anyone having a similar issue